# The URL '/wd/hub/session//moveto' did not map to a valid resource

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation

I am trying to click the element in hybrid application using AppiumDriver, using below code

```
AppiumDriver<IWebElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri(serverUri), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Constants.DriverWaitTime));

driver.FindElement(By.Id("xyz")).Click();
```

**//This gives an error saying. Element is not clickable since other element would receive a click.**

Due to this I tried using Action class (not successful everytime)

```
private static Actions actions = new Actions(Client.AppiumDriver);
private static IWebElement element = null;

element = Client.AppiumDriver.FindElement(By.Id(locator));
actions.MoveToElement(element, 10, 10).Click().Perform();
```

But it seems Action class is not reliable,

50% of the time action breaks throwing error **"The URL '/wd/hub/session//moveto' did not map to a valid resource"**

I Tried putting waits, Letting elements load completely but still I get above error

Has any one faced the similar problem?? If yes, then please help.

Here is the Appium log

```
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/9aaf70d4-8384-4c54-8386-62e40a3edea7/element/5017/enabled 200 515 ms - 76 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/9aaf70d4-8384-4c54-8386-62e40a3edea7/element {"using":"id","value":"hp_takePhoto"}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["id","hp_takePhoto","9aaf70d4-8384-4c54-8386-62e40a3edea7"]
[debug] [iOS] Executing iOS command 'findElement'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 5000 ms for condition
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Executing 'find_element' atom in default context
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending javascript command (function(){return function...
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending WebKit data: {"method":"Runtime.evaluate...
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Receiving WebKit data: {"result":{"result":{"type"...
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found handler for message '42'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received result for atom 'find_element' execution: {"ELEMENT":":wdc:1474455901436"}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"5018"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/9aaf70d4-8384-4c54-8386-62e40a3edea7/element 200 514 ms - 90 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session//moveto {"element":"5018","xoffset":10,"yoffset":10}
[debug] [HTTP] No route found. Setting content type to 'text/plain'
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session//moveto 404 1 ms - 65
```

When the step gets successfully executed logs are like

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/c3924633-053a-450b-a3fb-2600c00655c5/element {"using":"id","value":"hp_takePhoto"}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["id","hp_takePhoto","c3924633-053a-450b-a3fb-2600c00655c5"]
[debug] [iOS] Executing iOS command 'findElement'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 5000 ms for condition
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Executing 'find_element' atom in default context
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending javascript command (function(){return function...
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending WebKit data: {"method":"Runtime.evaluate...

[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Receiving WebKit data: {"result":{"result":{"type"...
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found handler for message '30'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received result for atom 'find_element' execution: {"ELEMENT":":wdc:1474457829048"}

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"5012"}

[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/c3924633-053a-450b-a3fb-2600c00655c5/element 200 511 ms - 90 

[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/c3924633-053a-450b-a3fb-2600c00655c5/execute {"script":"arguments[0].click()","args":[{"ELEMENT":"5012","element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"5012"}]}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.execute() with args: ["arguments[0].click()",[{"ELEMENT":"5012","element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"5012"}],"c3924633-053a-450b-a3fb-2600c00655c5"]
[debug] [iOS] Executing iOS command 'execute'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Executing 'execute_script' atom in default context
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending javascript command (function(){return function...
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending WebKit data: {"method":"Runtime.evaluate...

[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Receiving WebKit data: {"result":{"result":{"type"...

[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found handler for message '31'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received result for atom 'execute_script' execution: null

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.execute() result: null

[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/c3924633-053a-450b-a3fb-2600c00655c5/execute 200 513 ms - 76
```

Comment: Why are you moving to the element using offset?? This wouldn't be stable for every run..

Comment: Because MoveToElement clicks on left most point of element. Sometimes it by mistakely clicks on another adjacent element. Just to make sure correct element is click I am using it..

Comment: I tried without offset as well but still issue persists..:(

Comment: Try using `JavascriptExecutor` then..

Comment: Any link which would make a difference. Very new to these stuff.. Sorry for being lazy

Comment: Try as `IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor; js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur still getting the same error .. "The URL '/wd/hub/session//execute' did not map to a valid resource"

Comment: Added appium log. Please have a look.